# Date Picker doesn't show on PHP input created inside for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I am creating inputs dynamically inside a php foreach loop. I am assigning a class date-pick to the textboxes where I am suppose to add the datepicker. After the loop, the date-picker appears only on the first instance and the rest do not have. Aside from this, it causes my other jquery to fail, showing an error on console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null date.js:477`

Here is my php code for the loop:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$poterms; $i++)
{
   $lastcb=$lastcb+ 1;
   $nextdate=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($nextdate. ' + 30 days'));
 ?>
   <tr class="row1">
   <td><input  class="date-pick" value="<?php echo $nextdate; ?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="chkno" name="CheckNo" id="CheckNo<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $lastcb;?>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="chkval" name="Amount" value="<?php echo $checkamt;?>" onKeyup ="updatechecktotal()" /></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
   $nextdate=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($nextdate. ' + 30 days'));
}
?>
```

Here is where i call the datepicker function:

```
$(function()
{
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

Here is the part where the error is pointed at date.js

```
Date.fromString = function(s)
{
var f = Date.format;
var d = new Date('01/01/1970');
if (s == '') return d;
    s = s.toLowerCase();
var matcher = '';
var order = [];
var r = /(dd?d?|mm?m?|yy?yy?)+([^(m|d|y)])?/g;
var results;
while ((results = r.exec(f)) != null)
{
    switch (results[1]) {
    case 'd':
    case 'dd':
    case 'm':
    case 'mm':
    case 'yy':
    case 'yyyy':
    matcher += '(\\d+\\d?\\d?\\d?)+';
    order.push(results[1].substr(0, 1));
    break;
    case 'mmm':
    matcher += '([a-z]{3})';
    order.push('M');
    break;
  }
if (results[2]) {
matcher += results[2];
}

}
var dm = new RegExp(matcher);
var result = s.match(dm);
for (var i=0; i<order.length; i++) {
    var res = result[i+1]; //line 477
    switch(order[i]) {
    case 'd':
    d.setDate(res);
    break;
    case 'm':
    d.setMonth(Number(res)-1);
    break;
    case 'M':
    for (var j=0; j<Date.abbrMonthNames.length; j++) {
        if (Date.abbrMonthNames[j].toLowerCase() == res) break;
    }
    d.setMonth(j);
    break;
    case 'y':
    d.setYear(res);
    break;
    }
    }

    return d;
};
```

This drives me crazy...

Comment: Have you verified the generated HTML to ensure it's valid? It's hard to figure out only from the PHP source...

Comment: yes, I think it's valid. what puzzles me is why it appears only on the first though they have the same class.

Comment: Well, it means that result[] is null, so that's where to start looking and work your way up. If you're getting an error like that it makes sense that the js wont' continue to work for the following elements.  Also, is the $checkamt; defined somewhere before you are calling it there?

Comment: $checkamt is something that i use for some computations. I dont have issues with the rest of the variables. It's just the datepicker. I have read about binding events in javascript, but I do not know how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned a class to the  where the date-picker is supposed to be placed and creted functons to append the content of the td:

```
$(function()
{
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});

function createNewDatepickerInput() 
{
    var $newdatepick = $('<input name="date1" class="date-pick"/>');
    $datepick.appendTo(".dateclass").datepicker();
}
```

and this did the trick :) Thanks for the comments :)